# Add user to OG based on roles?

Tags: organic-groups, users

I am using drupal 7, I want to add **users** having **role 'R'** to a **OG group 'G'.**

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I've used, you can't add the role condition to EntityFieldQuery so the array needs to be filtered afterwards:

```
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
      ->propertyCondition('uid', '1', '>'); // skip the anonymous and admin
  $entities = $query->execute();
  $uids = array_keys($entities['user']);
  $accounts = user_load_multiple($uids);

  // filter the users array by role
  $include_roles = array('my_role', 'my_other_role');
  $filter = function ($value) use ($include_roles) {
        $isect = array_intersect($include_roles, $value->roles);
        return !empty($isect);
      };
  $accounts = array_filter($accounts, $filter);
```

Then, to add these to your group having id $gid

```
  foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    og_group($gid, array('entity' => $account, 'state' => OG_STATE_ACTIVE));
  }
```

Hope this helps. I think this should be doable in Rules, but I'm no expert in that.

Comment: Yes, seems you can make a Rule that gets run on "After updating an existing user account"/"After saving a new user account", set a "User has role(s)" condition and "Subscribe user to group" in the action. Don't know how to do that on all existing users in Rules though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in which file do i add the snippet?

Comment: The quickest way is to use the Devel module to execute PHP on your site (do be careful with that and try it on a testing site first), or write a custom module (tutorial: http://drupal.org/node/1074360 ) and make a menu callback for the function that executes the code. For continously subscribing users that get role X into group Y it's best to use the Rules module as described - you wouldn't want to load and go through every single user more than once.

Comment: i am no good in using codes, but i will surely try to apply these codes.

Comment: Is this solved in any way? Can this be done with rules? Event: After saving a new user account, Condition: User has role(s)... but the action is a problem if you want to give that user an arbitrary group membership? (not from context but manually set the NID of the group).

Comment: You can add an arbitrary group by inserting an action "Add entity to group" and choosing "Direct input mode" for the group. There should be a select list with all the current groups on your site.